# Functions as return value in Pascal

Tags: function, return-value, pascal, freepascal

I want to return a function as a return value in Pascal.

Generally it should look something like this:

```
function a(function b: Integer): function : Integer;
begin
   a := b;
end;
```

but this doesn't work. I know that there is some problem with returning function as 
a return value from another function but as far as I know this code should somehow work

what am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

You need to define a function type to do what you want. See the following code example:

```
type
  TFunc = function: Integer;

function a(b: TFunc): TFunc;
begin
  a := b;
end;

function x: Integer;
begin
  x := 11;
end;

begin
  Writeln(a(@x));
end.
```